# Destructuring and reordering Array with ES6 and React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I wanted to use a destructuring solution to reorder my array within my React container which it should be pretty straight forward.
Given an array `a1 = ['hello', 'hi', 'hola']`

```
componentDidMount() {
  const { a1 } = this.props
  this.a2 = []
  [a2[2], a2[0], a2[1]] = a1  --> this line give an error!!
  console.log('new ordered array', a2) // ['hola', 'hello', 'hi'] --> this print properly my new array
}
```

If I try to console log or use it in render I got `undefined`
The error I got at that line is:

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property '#<Object>' of undefined`

I really don't get it why I can print the value correctly in the `console.log` but when I try to actually use it in the code it doesn't work.
It's maybe something React cycle related?
I also tried to use it within my state but got the same error.

Comment: Have a look at the line with the error, you have a dot (`.`) where a comma should be

Comment: It's called destructuring, not desconstructing.

Comment: thanks @PeterMader

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line gives you an error because this is one of those rare cases when automatic semicolon insertion lets you down. Never start new line with `(` or `[]`, otherwise interpreter considers it as continuation of the previous  line and treats `[` or `(` as property access operation or function invocation.

This will work:

```
this.a2 = [];
[a2[2], a2[0], a2[1]] = a1
```

Or this:

```
this.a2 = []
;[a2[2], a2[0], a2[1]] = a1
```

Comment: that's exactly what it was happening! 
Problem is" my lint won't allow me to add semicolon -.- frontend development, so much fun :) I anyway already solved in another way but at least now i know, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is an `.` instead of `,` in this line `[a2[2], a2[0]. a2[1]] = a1  --> this line give an error!!`

Comment: You are right but i just mistype the question here, in my actual code, there is a comma